# How to choose when we need to use "Monthly view" and "Weekly view"

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns

I'm doing a to-do-list app. I was wondering why some app using different 
 view like monthly , weekly view

Comment: You're asking why the apps provide different views? Because people need different views at different times. That seems an obvious answer. Were you asking something different?

Answer (score 1):

It really boils down to the level of detail of you to do list. You could have three different views in your app:

1. List view, where you display ToDo's by end date in ascending order
2. Week view, where you display ToDo's in a weekly calendar
3. Month view, where you display ToDo's in a monthly calendar

Instead of forcing your users to a specific view, you could leave the options to the users, and what suits them best in any given moment.